# Classify singularities (poles)

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following function 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{h(p-\log(\frac{h}{1-h}))}}$ on where $p$ is real.

Are the singularities at $0$ and $\frac{e^{p}}{e^{p}+1}$ removable? essential?

Thanks.